# XOR operator and char in C++

Tags: c++

Given the following code fragment in C++:

```
char a = 0x0a;
char b = 0x80;
char c = a ^ b;
```

what will happen behind the screen? When I use cout to output c, there was no output.
Will the char a and char b be converted to binary format? what's the format of c?

Comment: What will happen is you'll get the bitwise exclusive or of those two numbers, what else?

Comment: It's easy to find good explanation of this, for example in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C).

Comment: [This](http://img.c4learn.com/2012/03/Bitwise-XOR-Operator-in-Java-Programming-Language.png) happens.

Comment: @TomaszKłak I know exactly what is XOR operation. I was wondering why there is no output if I print c? Will a and b firstly be converted to binary then XOR?

Comment: xor of those two numbers (0x8a) is most likely not printable character in your system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

c will be 0x8a, which is usually not a printable character, see (e.g) http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/img/latin-iso-8859-1.gif

(neither are 0x0a (line feed) or 0x80)

cout will print the character corresponding to the value of c for char arguments, that's why you don't see any output.

You may want to use printf to print the numeric value of c, or cast c to an int.

You may also be interested in this question, which discusses printing binary numbers in C: [Is there a printf converter to print in binary format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format)

Answer (score 2):

All numbers in a computer are in binary format.

`0x0a`, a.k.a. `10` (ten), is represented as

> 1010

and `0x80`, a.k.a. `128`, is represented as

> 10000000

If you xor those, you get 138.

Apparently, your terminal doesn't output anything useful if you print the `char` 138.